# Error: Failed to fetch data from New Relic: {"error":"Invalid query key."}

Tags: python, newrelic

```
import csv
import sys
import tempfile
import requests
import boto3
import logging

nrql_query = 'SELECT count(newrelic.timeslice.value) as \'Throughput\' FROM Metric SINCE 1 month AGO WHERE ' \
             'appName in (\'PLA-prd-eadv2-api-pla', 'PLA-prod-glpanlyt-api-pla', 'PLA-prd-eassvc-svc-pla', \
    'PLA-prd-eamxb-api-pla', 'PLA-prd-perfsvc-svc-pla', 'prd-perfsvc-serive-pla', 'prd-en-api-engagement', \
    'pla-prd-an-api-analytics', 'PLA-prd-casvc-svc-pla', 'PLA-prd-itmsvc-service-pla', 'PLA-prd-pwapi-api-pla', \
    'PLA-prd-insdash-svc-pla', 'PLA-prd-insdash-svc-pla', 'PLA-prd-lads-service-pla', \
    'pla-instructor-dash-ui-prod', 'PLA-prd-ea-api-cl5', 'PLA-prd-lrnprfl-api-pla', 'pla-prd=ccf-api-dash', \
    'pla-settingapi-api-prod\') facet  appName'

new_relic_api_key = 'NRAK-HUM4U99N0BYP98LRC3SMW8GJWQ6'
csv_filename = 'spike_metrics.csv'

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('NewRelicCallingLambda.py')


def fetch_new_relic_data(api_key, nrql_query):
    base_url = 'https://insights-api.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/849516/query'
    headers = {
        'Api-Key': api_key,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    data = {
        'nrql': nrql_query
    }
    response = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, json=data)
    response_json = response.json()

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response_json['results'][0]['events']
    else:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch data from New Relic: {response.text}")


def save_to_csv(data, csv_filename):
    with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=data[0].keys())
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)


def upload_to_s3(bucket_name, file_path, object_key):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_file(file_path, bucket_name, object_key)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    new_relic_api_key = event['new_relic_api_key']
    nrql_query = event['nrql_query']
    s3_bucket_name = event['s3_bucket_name']
    s3_object_key = event['s3_object_key']

    try:
        logger.info("Fetching data from New Relic...")
        data = fetch_new_relic_data(new_relic_api_key, nrql_query)

        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode='w', suffix='.csv') as temp_csv_file:
            csv_filename = temp_csv_file.name
            save_to_csv(data, csv_filename)

        logger.info("Uploading CSV to S3...")
        upload_to_s3(s3_bucket_name, csv_filename, s3_object_key)

        logger.info("Data fetched from New Relic and uploaded to S3 successfully.")
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'Data fetched from New Relic and uploaded to S3 successfully.'
        }
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error: {str(e)}")
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': f"Error: {str(e)}"
        }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        result = fetch_new_relic_data(new_relic_api_key, nrql_query)
        save_to_csv(result, csv_filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

Well I'm new to Python and new relic as well, what Im doing is writing a function which will fetch data from new relic, and save that data in .csv file. Next upload that .csv file in aws S3 bucket and deploy this application on aws Lambda.

Before writing this script, I tested the nrql query in postman by giving same api-key, it worked.
Later, When I'm running the application, I'm getting the above error, when debugging it is showing 401 error.
Stucked here!

Answer (score 0):

That error message indicates the the query key is incorrect. To create the correct type of query key browse to the api key page within newrelic and then select from the side menu "Insights query keys". Follow that link and it will take you to the correct page to create a query key. Select the + next to the "Query Keys" header there and it will create a new query key for you. It also provides you with an example curl command on that page that looks something like this:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-Query-Key: NRIQ-..." "https://insights-api.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/<account id>/query?nrql=SELECT%20average(duration)%20FROM%20PageView"
```

Translating this into a requests call would look like the following:

```
r = requests.get(
   "https://insights-api.newrelic.com/v1/accounts/<account id>/query", 
   params={"nrql": "SELECT average(duration) FROM PageView"},
   headers={"X-Query-Key": "NRIQ-...", "Accept": "application/json"}
)
```